# Reverse the order of pairs of lines of a text file

Tags: text-processing

I would like reverse the order of pairs of lines of a text file (m3u playlist).

This is the original content of the m3u file:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXTINF:-1,AL: Klan HD (AL)
http://mydomain.org:8000/live/username/mypass/1.ts
#EXTINF:-1,AL: Klan HD Beckup
http://mydomain.org:8000/live/username/mypass/2.ts
#EXTINF:-1,AL: Klan Kosova
http://mydomain.org:8000/live/username/mypass/3.ts
#EXTINF:-1,AL: Klan Kosova (B)
http://mydomain.org:8000/live/username/mypass/4.ts
#EXTINF:-1,AL: Top Channel SD
http://mydomain.org:8000/live/username/mypass/5.ts
#EXTINF:-1,AL: Top Channel HD
http://mydomain.org:8000/live/username/mypass/6.ts
#EXTINF:-1,AL: Top Channel Beckup
http://mydomain.org:8000/live/username/mypass/7.ts
#EXTINF:-1,AL: TV Uskana
http://mydomain.org:8000/live/username/mypass/8.ts
```

I need to reverse it like this:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXTINF:-1,AL: TV Uskana
http://mydomain.org:8000/live/username/mypass/8.ts
#EXTINF:-1,AL: Top Channel Beckup
http://mydomain.org:8000/live/username/mypass/7.ts
#EXTINF:-1,AL: Top Channel HD
http://mydomain.org:8000/live/username/mypass/6.ts
#EXTINF:-1,AL: Top Channel SD
http://mydomain.org:8000/live/username/mypass/5.ts
#EXTINF:-1,AL: Klan Kosova (B)
http://mydomain.org:8000/live/username/mypass/4.ts
#EXTINF:-1,AL: Klan Kosova
http://mydomain.org:8000/live/username/mypass/3.ts
#EXTINF:-1,AL: Klan HD Beckup
http://mydomain.org:8000/live/username/mypass/2.ts
#EXTINF:-1,AL: Klan HD (AL)
http://mydomain.org:8000/live/username/mypass/1.ts
```

I have already got it like this:

```
http://mydomain.org:8000/live/username/mypass/8.ts
#EXTINF:-1,AL: TV Uskana
http://mydomain.org:8000/live/username/mypass/7.ts
#EXTINF:-1,AL: Top Channel Beckup
http://mydomain.org:8000/live/username/mypass/6.ts
#EXTINF:-1,AL: Top Channel HD
http://mydomain.org:8000/live/username/mypass/5.ts
#EXTINF:-1,AL: Top Channel SD
http://mydomain.org:8000/live/username/mypass/4.ts
#EXTINF:-1,AL: Klan Kosova (B)
http://mydomain.org:8000/live/username/mypass/3.ts
#EXTINF:-1,AL: Klan Kosova
http://mydomain.org:8000/live/username/mypass/2.ts
#EXTINF:-1,AL: Klan HD Beckup
http://mydomain.org:8000/live/username/mypass/1.ts
#EXTINF:-1,AL: Klan HD (AL)
#EXTM3U
```

But it isn't what I need.

Answer (score 2):

I'd print the header, swap lines in each pair then reverse the whole thing:

```
{ head -n 1; { sed -n 'h;n;G;p' | tac; } ; } < infile
```

Try `tail -r` if `tac` is not available on your system. Also, on some setups this won't work because their `head` is dumb and [won't comply with the standards](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap01.html) - the other quick way to do it is via `sed q`:

```
{ sed q; { sed -n 'h;n;G;p' | tail -r; } ; } < infile
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '#EXTM3U';grep -v ^#EXTM3U m3u |sed 'N;s/\n/ /'|sed -e 's/\(.*\)\(http.*\)$/\2\n\1/'|tac
```

Comment: Maybe you could use the hold space to move line 1? `sed -e '1{h;d}' -e '$!N; s/\(.*\)\n\(.*\)/\2\n\1/' -e '$G' file.m3u | tac`

Comment: Thanks so, how can save the change in the same file again ?

Comment: use temporary file

Comment: save the change in the same file, using `sponge`, from `moreutils`

Answer (score 0):

There's a shorter solution, without `tac`, but with only `head` and `sed` :

```
$ head -n 1 f;sed -n '1!{N;2,3!G;h;$p}' f;
#EXTM3U
#EXTINF:-1,AL: TV Uskana
http://mydomain.org:8000/live/username/mypass/8.ts
#EXTINF:-1,AL: Top Channel Beckup
http://mydomain.org:8000/live/username/mypass/7.ts
#EXTINF:-1,AL: Top Channel HD
http://mydomain.org:8000/live/username/mypass/6.ts
#EXTINF:-1,AL: Top Channel SD
http://mydomain.org:8000/live/username/mypass/5.ts
#EXTINF:-1,AL: Klan Kosova (B)
http://mydomain.org:8000/live/username/mypass/4.ts
#EXTINF:-1,AL: Klan Kosova
http://mydomain.org:8000/live/username/mypass/3.ts
#EXTINF:-1,AL: Klan HD Beckup
http://mydomain.org:8000/live/username/mypass/2.ts
#EXTINF:-1,AL: Klan HD (AL)
http://mydomain.org:8000/live/username/mypass/1.ts
```

Answer (score 0):

**Using Raku (formerly known as Perl_6)**

```
raku -e '.join("\n").put for lines.rotor(2).reverse;'
```

Sample Input:

```
#EXTINF:-1,AL: Klan HD (AL)
http://mydomain.org:8000/live/username/mypass/1.ts
#EXTINF:-1,AL: Klan HD Beckup
http://mydomain.org:8000/live/username/mypass/2.ts
#EXTINF:-1,AL: Klan Kosova
http://mydomain.org:8000/live/username/mypass/3.ts
#EXTINF:-1,AL: Klan Kosova (B)
http://mydomain.org:8000/live/username/mypass/4.ts
#EXTINF:-1,AL: Top Channel SD
http://mydomain.org:8000/live/username/mypass/5.ts
#EXTINF:-1,AL: Top Channel HD
http://mydomain.org:8000/live/username/mypass/6.ts
#EXTINF:-1,AL: Top Channel Beckup
http://mydomain.org:8000/live/username/mypass/7.ts
#EXTINF:-1,AL: TV Uskana
http://mydomain.org:8000/live/username/mypass/8.ts
```

Sample Output:

```
#EXTINF:-1,AL: TV Uskana
http://mydomain.org:8000/live/username/mypass/8.ts
#EXTINF:-1,AL: Top Channel Beckup
http://mydomain.org:8000/live/username/mypass/7.ts
#EXTINF:-1,AL: Top Channel HD
http://mydomain.org:8000/live/username/mypass/6.ts
#EXTINF:-1,AL: Top Channel SD
http://mydomain.org:8000/live/username/mypass/5.ts
#EXTINF:-1,AL: Klan Kosova (B)
http://mydomain.org:8000/live/username/mypass/4.ts
#EXTINF:-1,AL: Klan Kosova
http://mydomain.org:8000/live/username/mypass/3.ts
#EXTINF:-1,AL: Klan HD Beckup
http://mydomain.org:8000/live/username/mypass/2.ts
#EXTINF:-1,AL: Klan HD (AL)
http://mydomain.org:8000/live/username/mypass/1.ts
```

The nice thing about Raku is it supports Unicode out-of-the-box, so the Raku code above should be able to handle both `m3u` and `m3u8` (Unicode Playlists) with no difficulty.

Ignoring the first ("`#EXTM3U`") line for the moment, the Raku code is pretty straight-forward. Lines are read in (lazily), `rotor`-ed together in pairs, reverse-ordered, and printed with a `\n` newline in-between each pair.

[The only thing to remember with `rotor` is that it will silently drop elements at the end if there is an insufficient # of elements (e.g. lines) to complete a `rotor` "set". If you want to preserve incomplete "sets" at the end, use `batch` instead of `rotor`].

Oh yes, about that initial `#EXTM3U` line: in Raku it's probably easiest to interpose a call to `.skip(1)` after `lines` but before `.rotor`, and add that `#EXTM3U` line back manually at the end.

https://raku.org